# MassTransit via MSMQ is not working, why?

Tags: c#, masstransit

Here is my code for MassTransit.

The subscriber console app:

```
namespace ConsoleSubscriber
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("set up a subscriber");

            Bus.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.UseMsmq();
                config.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
                config.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                config.UseControlBus();
                config.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/test_end");
                config.Subscribe(s => s.Instance(new Consumer()).Permanent());                    
            });

            Console.Read();
        }         
    }

    public class Consumer : Consumes<Message>.All
    {
        public void Consume(Message message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start consuming message");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Ids))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no ids");     
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ids are " + message.Ids);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Message class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public string Ids { get; set; }
}
```

The publisher console app:

```
namespace ConsolePublisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Console.WriteLine("start publishing");

            // initialize bus 
            Bus.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.UseMsmq();
                config.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
                config.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
                config.UseControlBus();
                config.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/test_queue");
            });

            Bus.Instance.Publish(new Message());
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent 1");

            var msg2 = new Message() { Ids ="1,2,3,4" };
            Bus.Instance.Publish(msg2);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent 2");

            Console.Read();    
        }
    }
}
```

When I run these two console applications, it seems the messages are not picked up by the consumer. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Try putting a sleep in before calling publish. Multicast subscriptions can take a moment to get configured as the two instances are talking to each other. Also ensure you started the consumer before the publisher. Also replacing `config.Subscribe(s => s.Instance(new Consumer()).Permanent());` with `config.Subscribe<Consumer>();` might help.

There are other routing methods that can keep the subscription data between restarts of the process once you move forward. I would start to look at using the Subscription Service, static routing, or just using RabbitMQ once you get a handle on this.

Comment: thank you, yes. the issue is the timing, I have managed to put a sleep in for both sub and pub after the bus initialization. now the sub picks up the messages.

Comment: @Travis How many milliseconds would you suggest for minimum sleep?

Comment: It sorta depends on your network configuration and latency, but somewhere around 500-1000ms should likely be enough for multicast to do it's thing. (Around 1/2 to 1 second).

Comment: Nice, after checking my code half a day a `Thread.Sleep` after the bus initialization magically resolved publish issues.